# cascading required dropdowns in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Any idea on how to implement 2 **Required** cascading dropdowns in ASP.Net MVC? I am stressin on the attribute [Required] because I already created the cascading dropdowns. My issue is, the child dropdown should show depending on certain values of the parent dropdown. But since both are decorated with the Required attribute, in case the child dropdown is not shown, the form does not submit. which is normal since both dropdowns are part of the form. How can I implement both dropdowns to be required but only if the child is visible on the form? is JavaScript the only way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Why would only the 2nd dropdownlist be shown (it suggests your not understanding how to create cascading dropdownlists)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it's the way it is designed. The second Dropdown shows only when certain specific values from the parent dropdown are selected. but one of the child dropdown value has to be selected. If the child dropdown is shown, the user sees that the child dropdown is required. if the child dropdown is not shown, under the hood it is still required, hence the form is not submitted since the ModelState is invalid thanks to the child dropdown not being set any value.

Comment: Then use a conditional validation attribute, for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery Validation Plugin, required only if #other is selected:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    dropdown1: {
      required: true
    },
    dropdown2: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $("#dropdown1").val() != "";
      }
    }
  }
});
```